# unexpected error after "for in" and before "do"

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

So I am experimenting with batch scripting and am trying to make something similar to snake. But I ran into a problem that I have no idea what causes it. Just when my first loop for start I get unexpected error about ")" after 3. I tried making another variable which has "1 2 3" and use that instead but still got almost same results. Just now it showed that do was unexpected.

Of course I can use if statements which obviously work as well but I was experimenting with goto to see if the speed of the script would increase. Because using if's it takes at least half or less second to output 3 lines.

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
mode con: cols=50 lines=25
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo. > test.txt
set array[1]=2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
set array[2]=2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
set array[3]=2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
for %%b in (1, 2, 3) do (
    for %%i in (!array[%%b]!) do (
        echo Loop Begins
        set LNr=%%i
        echo Loop%LNr%
        goto Loop%LNr%
        :Loop0
        echo 0
        echo|set /p ="░" >> test.txt
        goto LoopE
        :Loop1
        echo 1
        echo|set /p ="█" >> test.txt
        goto LoopE
        :Loop2
        echo 2
        echo|set /p = "#" >> test.txt
        goto LoopE
        :LoopE
    )
    echo. >> test.txt
)
echo. >> test.txt
```

Also, any idea what characters I could use in ANSI encoding to avoid having to use UTF-8 and changing CMD font?

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: goto breaks the FOR loops context. consider a subroutine

Comment: to generate all extended ASCII characters check this - [genchr](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-genchr.html) and just set a proper CHCP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works , though I'm not sure it produces desired output:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
mode con: cols=50 lines=25
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo. > test.txt
set array[1]=2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
set array[2]=2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
set array[3]=2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
for %%b in (1, 2, 3) do (
    for %%i in (!array[%%b]!) do (
        call :funct %%i
    )
    echo. >> test.txt
)
echo. >> test.txt
exit /b %errorlevel%

:funct
        echo Loop Begins
        set LNr=%1
        echo Loop%LNr%
        goto Loop%LNr%
        :Loop0
        echo 0
        echo|set /p ="░" >> test.txt
        goto LoopE
        :Loop1
        echo 1
        echo|set /p ="█" >> test.txt
        goto LoopE
        :Loop2
        echo 2
        echo|set /p = "#" >> test.txt
        goto LoopE
        :LoopE
        goto :eof
```

and generates file like

```
#░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░# 
#░░░░░░░░░░░░█░░░░░░░░░░░░░# 
#░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░#
```

GOTO breaks the for loop so you need subroutine.Also check the [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) docs. There a lot of ways to produce extended ASCII sharacters -[WSH/jscript/vbscript hybrid](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=33963), [certutil](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1562) , [forfiles](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=23888) ,[makecab](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-genchr.html).

Comment: thank you, yeah I thought that it had to do something with the goto's

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `for` loop in batch will work like this: `for /l %%b in (1,2,3) do (...)`.

**2.** It's a good practice to add quotation marks around the variables, especially contains spaces. E.g: `set "array[1]=2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2"`.
**3.** You can change the font via the registry key. 
  Reg key: `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont`
Change the value, E.g: `Lucida Console` has a value of `0`.
`reg /?` for more details to change programmatically.